# Como obter os índices da linha e da coluna de uma lista List<List<int>>?

Tags: c#, lista

Possuo uma lista que simula uma matriz (ou um array de duas dimensões) que esta estruturada da seguinte forma:

```
List<List<int>> matriz = new List<List<int>>();
```

Sendo que esta `matriz` está inicializada com os seguintes valores:

```
matriz.Add(new List<int> {3, 4, 1}  );
matriz.Add(new List<int> {2, 4, 5}  );
matriz.Add(new List<int> {44, 8, 9} );
```

E o meu problema é encontrar a posição da **linha** e da **coluna** dado um determinado valor. Por exemplo, o valor `44` se encontra na linha `2` e coluna `0`, veja:

```
matriz[2][0] // 44
```

Tentei utilizar o método `FindIndex` desta forma:

```
matriz.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(44))
```

Porém, ele só me retorna um único valor que é a posição correspondente a linha que é `2`, e eu precisaria da posição da linha e da coluna `2` e `0`.

## Pergunta

- Como eu poderia obter os índices correspondentes a linha e a coluna
  dado um determinado valor de uma lista `List<List<int>>`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode percorrer a lista utilizando [`ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) para descobrir a coluna:

```
int a = new int(),
    b = new int(),
    busca = 1;
a = matriz.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(busca));
matriz.ForEach(x => { if(x.Contains(busca)){ b = x.IndexOf(busca); } });
Console.WriteLine("Busca: {0}, Linha: {1}, Coluna: {2}", busca, a, b);
```

> Podes ver funcionando em [ideone](https://ideone.com/Lf5mS8)

Ou utilizar o [`for`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for):

```
int busca = 1;
for(int a = 0; a < matriz.Count; a++) {
  for(int b = 0; b < matriz[a].Count; b++) {
    if (matriz[a][b] == busca) {
      Console.WriteLine("Busca: {0}, Linha: {1}, Coluna: {2}", busca, a, b);
    }
  }
}
```

> Podes ver funcionando em [ideone](https://ideone.com/IBb4GP)

Comment: E se tiver outros itens com o mesmo item? Irá causar confusão no Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
    static int GetIndex(List<List<int>> array, int line, int column)
    {
        // índice atual
        int temp_index = 0;
        // percorre nas linhas até onde você quer ir
        for(int x = 0; x <= line; x++)
        {
            // se for a linha desejada, percorre nas colunas dela
            if(x == line)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y <= column; y++)
                {
                    temp_index++; /* irá parar sozinho quando chegar na coluna desejada */
                }
            } else temp_index += array[x].Count; /* adiciona as colunas no índice */
        }
        return temp_index - 1; /* retorna o índice zero-based index */
    }
```

Esse método irá percorrer na sua matriz, e não precisa ter um tamanho fixo para cada linha, portanto, cada linha pode ter x elementos que não irá inteferir no índice final.

> Obs.: remova o `- 1` no final se não quiser um índice baseado em posição zero.

Modo de uso:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<int>> matriz = new List<List<int>>();
        matriz.Add(new List<int> { 3, 4, 1 });
        matriz.Add(new List<int> { 2, 4, 5 });
        matriz.Add(new List<int> { 44, 8, 9 });

        Console.WriteLine(GetIndex(matriz, 1, 1)); // 4, index 4
        Console.WriteLine(GetIndex(matriz, 2, 0)); // 44, index 6
        Console.WriteLine(GetIndex(matriz, 0, 3)); // 1, index 3

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```